# PHP - Call a function with no return that does actually change values

Tags: php, function, methods, void

I want to call a function in PHP, that changes existing variables without returning a specific one.

**Here an example:**

```
<?php
  $number1 = 5;
  $number2 = 3;
  echo $number1;
  echo $number2; //shows the unmodified numbers

  modifyNumbers($number1, $number2); // Modifies the Numbers

  echo $number1;
  echo $number2; //shows the modified numbers
?>

<!-- Stuff -->

<?php
  function modifyNumbers($number1, $number2) {
    /* Doing math stuff with the numbers */
    /* No return because many numbers were changed / overwritten
  }
?>
```

*Basically, I want to make a function that is just overwriting variables instead of giving a specific value back to a specific variable where the function is called.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the reference of the variables.

Comment: you need to define the variables as global

Comment: Define as global worked great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pass by reference with &

```
<?php
  $number1 = 5;
  $number2 = 3;
  echo $number1;
  echo $number2; //shows the unmodified numbers

  modifyNumbers($number1, $number2); // Modifies the Numbers

  echo $number1;
  echo $number2; //shows the modified numbers
?>

<!-- Stuff -->

<?php
  function modifyNumbers(&$number1, &$number2) {
    $number1++;
    $number2--;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Precede the arguments with an ampersand.

```
function modifyNumbers(&$number1, &$number2) {
    /* Doing math stuff with the numbers */
    /* No return because many numbers were changed / overwritten
  }
```

This way, a reference is created and everything you do with the variable will affect the variable 'outside' the function.

Comment: Awesome, even shorter than define the variables as global :)